# Snap method for Java console game

Tags: java

I've just put together one of my first full Java programs for practice. It is a simple snap game but I'm not happy with the method for the actual "Snap" condition.  I may be being fussy but I wonder if there is something better someone could suggest?

```
public static boolean snap() {
    Scanner response = new Scanner(System.in);
    double compReflex = (Math.random() * (1000 - 250 + 1)) + 250;
    long reflex = Math.round(compReflex);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("go");
    response.nextLine();

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startTime + reflex) {
        System.out.println("I win");
        response.close();
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        System.out.println("Well done");
        response.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The issue is I would like the `else` clause to happen immediately if a button was pressed and the `if=True` clause to happen automatically after the `reflex` delay if the button isn't pressed. At the moment enter has to be pressed and then the computer judges who had the shortest reaction time. Which isn't snap...

I looked at KeyListeners but they only seem to be available for UI's such as JSwing? I also looked at thread interruption but couldn't work out how to trigger a thread interrupt and then handle the exceptions with the correct program flow? Or is it is even possible?

I think it needs to be a multi-threaded solution but don't fully have a handle on concurrency/multi-threading yet so any really good learning resources appreciated in addition to solutions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking and answering specific technical questions. "Help me make my program better" isn't quite specific. We're not here to make design decisions for you, but rather, to explain why some particular mechanism works the way it does. You might get more support for this type of query at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You'll also want to review the SO help file section covering what's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: Codereview is for having people suggest improvements to working code. This code is not working, because it doesn't do what it should. OP is asking how to do a non-blocking read from `System.in`. That is a "specific technical question", and on topic here.

Comment: @meriton OP's question, if we're being generous, is meandering and includes a series of vague complaints, some of which you value more highly, and others of which I value more highly. I see "help me make my code better." You see "it doesn't do what I want." The bottom line is that if there's a question here, it's worded so vaguely as to lead to ambiguous interpretations. I think it's off topic. I see how you think it is. The real point is that it's a poor written question which is more worthy of an edit or being closed rather than receiving an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the console API weren't so dreadfully old, you could simply do something like

```
try {
    System.in.readLine(100, TimeUnit.MILLIS);
    System.out.println("You win!");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Too slow!");
}
```

but unfortunately, the API to read from a console was defined in the very first release of the Java programming language, and not reworked since, so it doesn't allow reading with a timeout. If a thread reads from an InputStream, it won't stop reading until there is data, the InputStream itself signals an error, or the entire JVM exits.

So if you really want to do this, you'd need something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var readerThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try (var scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            scanner.nextLine();
            gameOver(true);
        }
    });
    readerThread.setDaemon(true); // this thread should not inhibit JVM termination

    readerThread.start();
    System.out.println("Go!");
    sleep(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    gameOver(false);
}

static void sleep(int duration, TimeUnit unit) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(unit.toMillis(duration));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

synchronized static void gameOver(boolean victory) {
    if (!over) {
        System.out.println(victory ? "You win!" : "I win!");
        over = true;
    }
}

static boolean over;
```

A few things to note here:

- Since the two threads race to gameOver, we need to ensure they don't both execute it. By making the method synchronized, we ensure that the threads will execute it after each other, and by setting a boolean, we can detect whether the other thread was faster.
- everything is static because we can't cancel the reading thread. Granted, we could keep it running and reuse it for the next instance of the game, but it would eat any console input in the meantime (such as the answer to "do you want to try again?"), which is annoying. So I am not going to pretend that this solution is nice and reusable, and thus can make my life easier by making everything static.
- the try-with-resources statement is a compact way to close a resource (such as a `Scanner`) once we are done with it.
- the utility method for sleep is just to move the pointless, but required, catch block out of the main method, so the main method is easier to read.